# AWS security groups for Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm working on setting up a Cassandra cluster with Datastax OpsCenter. I'm following the instructions [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-to-create-a-datastax-enterprise-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-in-ten-minutes), and I am currently setting up the OpsCenter server. On the firewall creation[step](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/dse_firewall_ports) for the instance, my plan was to put all the future Cassandra nodes in a security group and allow access to most the ports (except 22, 8888, etc) only from this security group. This is the most sane way I could think of doing it, but since this is my first time setting this up, anyone have any other approaches? I am assuming the OpsServer panel will allow creating nodes with my security group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use OpsCenter cloud provisioning, it can create a security group specifically for Cassandra/OpsCenter that has only needed ports open. However if that’s not an option, the guide you’ve linked to ([here’s a DSE 4.5 version](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfFirePort.html)) should work too since you can select existing security group during OpsCenter provisioning.